# How to close self (popup window) after php back-end process

Tags: php

1. Launch a popup window using Javascript and pass data with using GET method
2. At the popup window, client able to select item to Delete (unique ID) also using GET method, example onClick=window.open(\'backprocess.php?UID=12345\',\'_self\')
3. At backprocess.php; get the UID and remove from database (mysql)
4. Once it done, i want to close this pop-up window

*i'm stop #4, i try window.close, it close directly without process

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by 'it close directly without process' ?

Comment: #3. php get UID from GET, then query mysql to DELETE FROM tbl WHERE UID=12345, once this process is done(comfirm) then ONLY close this POPUP window

Comment: Rather than using popup windows to run scripts and pass data, perhaps a better solution would be to use AJAX? That way your delete script will run in the background. You won't have to worry about closing popups once the processing has finished.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this

<script>
$('.id_submit').click(function()
{
    var IdToDelete=$('#IdToDelete').val();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"GET",
            url:"backprocess.php?UID="+IdToDelete,
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(result)
            {
                if(result=='Deleted')
                {

                    $('#popup').hide();

                }

            }
        });



});

</script>

in backprocess.php

if(isset($_GET['UID']))
{
$deleteId=$_GET['UID'];
//your query
echo "Deleted";
}
```